# How do I send my command history to two different history files?

Tags: linux, shell, history, ksh

Is there any way to have my commands sent to a secondary history file besides the default history location? I know that setting `HISTFILE` will send my commands to a custom locations, but I still want commands sent to the original location.

The use case is that commands are being run on a single machine by multiple users that are all using the same linux account. I'd like to be able to tee command history to a more session based history file. The session can be defined by some environment variable that the user sets, for example.

Maybe I am doing it wrong, but I have tried the [`trap ... DEBUG` strategy](https://blog.fpmurphy.com/2014/07/korn-shell-debug-trap.html) but it also executes after all the commands in my `PS1`. I've also tried to set my `PS4` and running `set -x`, but I still get an extra empty line after every command I run.

Comment: The history is not intended to be a log. It is intended as a way to reuse commands. I think there is no coherent way to use two history lists at a time. Possible options: (1) totally independent history file per session; (2) saving a copy of history upon exit, per session (the copy may include previous entries from previous session(s)); (3) an actual log which is conceptually different than history. Also: how hard do you need spoofing the results to be?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski thanks for your comment! What do you mean by spoofing the results? And I understand what you're saying - I am slightly misusing the history functionality but it pretty much mimics exactly what I need. As for your solutions above - (1) there is a hard organizational requirement to have the global history file. (2) it is pretty common to have multiple people logged in simultaneously, so the session history files would have unrelated commands. (3) i am okay with, but not sure how to get there without modifying the ksh binary. Thanks!

Comment: Spoofing: Usually any user can modify what their current shell considers the history; the history file is under the user's control; shell settings are under the user's control. So if you need an additional file for the sake of auditing (which session did what) then history is not the right way.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Ah okay thanks for clarifying. I'll try to explore other alternatives.